# How to call the html function while loading the html file in webview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I was facing an issue for calling the htmnl function from xcode ,Here i am writing the code of both Html and objective-c ,

This is html function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function load(val)
        {
            alert(val);
            document.getElementById("h_dvid").value=val;
        } 

   </script>
```

In viewcontroller `viewdidload` i am calling that function like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 360)];
    [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                          pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
    [self.view addSubview:web];

    NSString* str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"load('%@')",@"hi"];

    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];

    web.delegate=self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

then i was not getting call the load function due to html file is not loaded fully so,
I had taken a button when i clicked on that button then i called the html function then its working fine.BUT i need to call HTML function in `viewdidload` itself.I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: Try,  [web loadHTMLString:@"<html>...</html>" baseURL:nil];

Comment: No, that is a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `loadRequest:` on `UIWebView` it will start loading the URL. This is asynchronous process. Until this completes, `UIWebView` will not have effect by calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method.

Implement this [`UIWebViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad%3a) method and call the required JS function.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString* str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"load('%@')",@"hi"];
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];
}
```

Hope that helps!